# Is the principle of charity just confirmation bias?

Tags: fallacies, metaphilosophy, secondary-literature

The principle of charity seems absolutely integral to studying philosophy in any way at all.

How does an overlap of charity and confirmation bias work out, either in the class room or in philosophical literature etc.?

In the most general way, if we have to choose between A implies B or C implies D, then one form of the most "charitable" reading will be the 'letters' that cohere with our preconceptions better.

---

Having read some responses, I wanted to point out that I am not limiting confirmation bias to charitable readings or saying that fallacious reasoning does not often display these biases, but asking whether it is puzzling at all how this principle of reasoning allows cognitive bias in a way that e.g. avoiding the fallacy of reification might not.

Comment: "*Whether the stone hits the pitcher, or the pitcher hits the stone, it will be bad for the pitcher.*"

Comment: The principle of charity requires one to interpret arguments in the strongest way one can manage. Of course, what they can (or wish to) manage is affected by their biases and other intellectual flaws, confirmation bias is just one from a long list. If anything, charity is there to counter biases. It is hard to see how one can even be mistaken for the other, let alone "just" be it.

Comment: @Conifold apologies for the hyperbole.  so you think that charity always or just usually counters confrimation bias?

Comment: It is a norm aimed at countering biases when arguments go against them, along with other intellectual norms. Of course, the arguments need not go against them, always or usually, but that is not when following it matters.

Comment: it seems badly desigend to counter this particular bias. that's all i was asking about @Conifold hasty generalisation! i jest

Comment: Why? If an argument leads to an undesirable conclusion one's inclination is to erect a strawman and tilt at that (as we can amply see on this site, among many other places). If one makes an honest effort to follow charity this inclination is checked.

Comment: becasue what counts, or we believe amounts to, an honest - charitable - effort depends on what we already believe, rather than virtuous idk striving after knowledge @Conifold ? or often does. if i read the tractatus as being all nonsense vs just concluding with it, that will likely reflect how i already viewed philosophy. both a good (due to the flag at the beginning) and bad (due to how radical it is) example

Comment: Yes, but any norm is "badly designed" in this way. People are well known for breaking norms when it suits them, or even for leveraging them by "robbing Peter to pay Paul" and the like. Norms describe what *should* happen, what *does* happen, always or usually, is another story, with biases in the leading roles.

Comment: @Conifold what biases are there involved in avoiding a hasty generalization? you may say any number of them, if used badly. but my point is that sometimes you need biases to get the principle of charity to work at all.

Comment: then apply that biased readings not just to reading philsoophy on-line but your ethical knowledge, and you might see how weird it is @Conifold all we are doing is confirming to ourselves or someone else (or being epiphainic) that we were already right about the difference between good and bad conduct, whenever we read about ethics (at least if we are being charitable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thas not how the principle of charity (poc) works.

The principle asks you to read and present *any* text and argument as strong as possible, *even if you disagree with it*.

Now, what happens if you do happen to agree with a given argument? Do you need the poc to tell you that you need to read it carefully and make it strong? No, you will engage with the text and make it strong *due to the fact that you agree with it*. That is (part of) what we call confirmation bias. The poc only gains practical importance the moment we *lack internal motivation to engage with a given text in the same way*.

It makes us engage with arguments more deeply *with which we do not want to engage* (due to confirmation bias).

Now, when that happens and we seriously follow it with a given text or argument we initially disagree with, there are three possible outcomes:

1. We come to realise that we have overseen or underappteciated important arguments that make the position actually the better one, ie. we find ourselves *changing our initial position*.
2. We may not be convinced by the argument or agree with it, but better understand its historical, systematic, and/or conceptual *place*, ie. we learned to *appreciate it and pin it down*.
3. We find that the argument actually is rubbish since we convinced ourselves that there is not enough valid argument in favour and there are glaring holes everywhere but can pinpoint these much more precisely than before now.

All three outcomes help us in better appreciating and writing about positions *we initially would never have cared to elaborate on in this depth* due to confirmation bias. That's why the poc is important and works diametrically to the bias.

Comment: Little comment on that: A very real problem in current academic teaching and practice is that people are taught to and work almost exclusively with (very recently published) secondary sources and rarely engage with the primary sources. It is hard to write a good, in-depth, charitable interpretation of Plato, Kant, Descartes or you name them when your only way to them is through the lense of someone writing about them based on a translation, several hundreds of years later, though.

Comment: i think this is the right answer. while reading philosophy chairtably *can* involve confirmation bias, the poc acts to change our beliefs and so is one way to avoid the bias.

Answer (score 1):

The principle of charity is an *antidote* to confirmation bias, but only **if** you apply it to your opponents arguments but not your own.

I recommend to my graduate students that they perform research in the way a good chess player plays chess.  A good chess player doesn't play the strongest move they can find, they play the move for which their opponents best reply is the weakest.  Similarly when making a (scientific) claim, don't make the strongest argument that *can* be supported by the data, make the argument that "reviewer 3" can find the least to criticise.  This is basically operating the principle of charity with "reviewer 3", by being your own "reviewer 3" *before* submitting the paper.

I suspect there are other examples of how taking opposing views charitably is a good practical heuristic.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmation bias is a tendency to filter information to find a subset that justifies what you already believe. So if you present an ambiguous argument to me, one with a conclusion I don't like, I might focus on a particular interpretation of it, or a particular weakness within it, in order to rubbish the argument and discredit the conclusion- that's a form of confirmation bias. On the other hand, if I put my biases to one side and tried to put the most constructive interpretation on what you are trying to say, regardless of whether your conclusions did or didn't agree with my prior beliefs, I would be acting in accordance with the principle of charity.

You could, I suppose, define a belief in the importance of the principle of charity as being a bias, and therefore you could say that regarding an argument with the charitable eye was a sort of confirmation bias, but that would be an unhelpful blurring of an important distinction.

Comment: i don't think your answer is at all correct (or rather, it does not answer the question). while it is true that confirmation bias can lead to confirming a bias that i am wrong, the question is whether - suppose you can leave aside who is speaking - as that is - or tends to be - a fallacy - it is more likely - or at least often the case - that charity will lead to confrimation bias than otherwise.

Comment: the problem is that if you see "a conclusion I don't like.... a particular interpretation of it, or a particular weakness within it", then that itself is not - in ignoring more charitable readings - "confrimation bias" - rather than a lack of charity - unless the bias is that you should lack charity. which is fine and all, but not at all "helpful". 
i am not trying to "blur" anything and suggesting i am is not an answer to the question that was asked

Comment: i guess an actual answer is that, supposing you use the principle of charity, this may well lead to confirmation bias, but if you do not, then the latter will get in through the back door anyway. without the principle of charity we end up committing any number of fallacies, and these will also lead to confirmation bias (a straw man will be based on our preconceptions etc.). but the link between bias and fallacy - rather than an absence of one - is less interesting.

Comment: @prof_post Confirmation bias leads you to endorsing and more carefully reading arguments you agree to anyways. The principle of charity makes you read an argument more carefully that you would have discarded or read only superficially due to conformation bias, since it runs *against your own intuition*. You seem to have an agenda here, not a question. It's simply true that in academia and philosophy as a whole, one tends to act like described and the principle helps countering this tendency. What may, in theory, happen as well is irrelevant to that fundamental fact.

Comment: no there's no agenda lol @PhilipKlöcking